# How many Month are there according to acnod

Tags: sql

i want to see only the month except of multiple entries here is my code

```
select aclist.acnod,journaldt.JRENTDATE
 from JOURNALDT
inner join ACLIST on aclist.ACNO = JOURNALDT.ACNO
where aclist.acnod like '3.4.6.%.%'
order by acnod, JRENTDATE asc
```

and here is my result

[image: this is result]

i want to see the result like this

here you can see i work with code number 3.4.6.1.1 
  month 6  i want to see the 1 number only 6 ahead of acnod  except of 6 entries 
like below

[image]

Please help out

Comment: Is 6 the number of months, or the last month (June)?

Comment: no dec is last of month but i just wanna see the month that how many month are there

i just wanna see the number of month you can say duration between starting and ending

the month between two date

Comment: Please tag the database you are using

Comment: SQL SERVER SERVER 2014 R2

Answer (score 0):

Try this and replace value with column name.

```
select SUBSTRING(val,1,CHARINDEX('.',val,1)-1) as Month from
(
select SUBSTRING('3.4.6.1',CHARINDEX('.','3.4.6.1',3)+1,CHARINDEX('.','3.4.6.1',4)) as val
)t;
```

Answer (score 0):

The "6" could be a lot of things.  It could be the number of rows in the table:

```
select aclist.acnod, count(*)
from JOURNALDT inner join
     ACLIST
     on aclist.ACNO = JOURNALDT.ACNO
where aclist.acnod like '3.4.6.%.%'
group by aclist.acnod;
```

It could be the the maximum month:

```
select aclist.acnod, max(month(journaldt.JRENTDATE))
from JOURNALDT inner join
     ACLIST
     on aclist.ACNO = JOURNALDT.ACNO
where aclist.acnod like '3.4.6.%.%'
group by aclist.acnod;
```

It could be the duration.  Date/time functions vary by database, but here is typical syntax:

```
select aclist.acnod, datediff(month, min(journaldt.JRENTDATE), max(journaldt.JRENTDATE))
from JOURNALDT inner join
     ACLIST
     on aclist.ACNO = JOURNALDT.ACNO
where aclist.acnod like '3.4.6.%.%'
group by aclist.acnod;
```

It could be the fifth character:

```
select distinct aclist.acnod, substr(aclist.acnod, 5, 1)
from JOURNALDT inner join
     ACLIST
     on aclist.ACNO = JOURNALDT.ACNO
where aclist.acnod like '3.4.6.%.%';
```

And no doubt there are other interpretations as well.